# Is there a decent icon editor for OS X capable of editing .icns files?

Tags: software-recommendation, icon

The software for editing icons needs to run on OSX Lion.

Comment: I found a windows application claiming to do *.icns file, but it would be really humiliating to revert to Windows to edit Mac icon files because no software is available for mac that I could find.

Comment: I strongly suggest people to look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13127142/1011366) (it gives information on how to access the images embedded inside an ICNS file) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20703594/1011366) (which is a script that generates an ICNS from a single image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is depends on the kind of editing you need to do. [icns Editor](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icns-editor/id419738444?mt=12) is on the App Store. Maybe [this one](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icon-maker/id430202307?mt=12) too?

Comment: Both of those are dead links now. Any idea where they can be found these days?

Answer (score 20):

In 10.5+, Apple's built-in **Preview.app** lets you do edit `.icns` files!

(Preview used to be pretty bare-bones back in 10.2 days, but with every OS release it has gotten more and more powerful.)

After opening the file, use the up/down arrow keys to switch between the different sized icon and bitmask images contained in the .icns file.

Then with each image you can:

- Cut/Copy/Paste
- Annotate (draw rectangles, add text, lines, arrows, ...)
- Change transparency
- Scale
- Adjust color (saturation, tint, sharpness, etc)

Comment: I can't figure out how to Paste a single image over an icns file opened in Preview on 10.9.2. Paste is never enabled. Does that still work for you?

Comment: You can cut (clear) and paste. But before hitting cmd+X or cmd+V, you need to select an area with the rectangular selection tool, to act as a "target" of the clipboard operation. If you select an area alrger than the icon size, it will automatically clip to its bounds (e.g., 1024 x 1024).

Comment: This info was really helpful for visually distinguishing an app I use two versions of on the same machine. I created a desaturated icon for the legacy version.

Answer (score 6):

***EDIT:*** This answer is now out of date. Apple recommends using "Asset Libraries" instead of creating `icns` files.

<s>Apple provides Icon Composer as part of their free developer tools.</s>

This is the only officially sanctioned way to create icns files. Most other editors don't support all the possible features.

The idea is you create a png file for each size you want, then create an icns file in Icon Composer, and import your various png files into it.

Comment: Note: per Apple, Icon Composer doesn't handle @2x icons: "Note: Don’t use Icon Composer—it can’t create high-resolution icns files."

Comment: As of XCode 8.2, Icon Composer is no longer available in Additional Tools, as it cannot create high resolution icons.

Comment: That being the case, what does Apple recommend for such delicate work? what do THEY use for designing their icons?

Comment: @MottiShneor Icon Composer has been replaced with the xcassets system which is just a json file listing various png files and Xcode has a nice GUI to generate the json code. Any image editor that can create png files will work fine and individual employees at Apple would have their personal favourite, but Sketch has to be as close to "the" standard as you can get. In particular it has great tools for dealing with all the different pixel resolutions required for icons.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that the program [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/) would be a good place to start for designing icon art as well as all manner of math and code drawing options.

It was designed from the ground up to do vector drawing and output many sizes of a master drawing as needed for icons to work well. Due to both limited resolutions for small icons as well as beefy artwork scaled up for resolution independence, the layers and tools work well.

The free trial should let you know if the tutorials and help on building icons is suitable for your skill level and needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use web tools:
1. Create: http://www.xiconeditor.com/
2. Convert: http://iconverticons.com/online/